# Unable to start the mysql server in ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04

After running the command 
`mysql -v` in Ubuntu, I am getting the following error:

> **ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)**

Answer (score 74):

I think this is because you are using client software and not the server.

- `mysql` is client
- `mysqld` is the server

Try:

`sudo service mysqld start`

To check that service is running use: `ps -ef | grep mysql | grep -v grep`.

**Uninstalling:**

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

**Re-Installing:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

---

*For all the editors who make edits without any understanding of the subject: Please stop attempting to move this section to the top!*

**Previous steps did not work, anything else I can try?**

You could delete apt.conf.d folder and pull updates again. This is only needed in rare cases. It was much more common back in 2016 when this answer was originally written. Before executing following commands take a backup of entire folder, make a copy of it, or create an archive of it:

```
### EXECUTING THE FOLLOWING COMMAND CAN CAUSE HARM TO YOUR SYSTEM
### UNDERSTAND WHAT YOU ARE DELETING BEFORE PROCEEDING
sudo rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I am getting this error
Failed to start mysqld.service: Unit mysqld.service not found

Comment: How did you install it? Did you use `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`?

Comment: yes but got something like this:
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: It looks like it did not get installed correctly. You will need to delete what is there and reinstall. Uninstalling and removing config by: `sudo apt-get purge mysql-server`. This is a good step to run Autoclean and autoremove: `sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean`. Not to install run: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install mysql-server`. Hope this helps.

Comment: getting same error again 
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
 mysql-server
N: Ignoring file '50unattended-upgrades.ucf-old' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Backup folder. Remove `50unattended-upgr*` and re-run update & install. Updating all packages wouldn't hurt as well. See update to my answer.

Comment: If you dont want your data to be lost
`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server ` is enough

Comment: This worked for me, `sudo apt-get upgrade` triggered a message asking if I wanted to replace the deleted 50unattended-upgrades file with the manufacturer version. This defaults to no, so make sure you enter Y if you want that file to be replaced.

Comment: You should write this line "Backup entire folder before doing this:" above of the answer. because I read this line after uninstalling mysql but thank god I didn't had important database created

Comment: i tried with restarting mysql service no worked , then reinstall mysql client dependency and reconfigure mysql . and restarted the service again , everything works fine , sounds weird but works !   root case : in my case while trying to remove python ..stupid command removed few dependency also . so had to reinstall those

Comment: Worked for me.  I had MySQL Workbench, but it said that the server wasn't running.  It wasn't until I did the server install listed above that I could create schemas/tables etc.

Answer (score 6):

By default, apt install MariaDB but not mySQL.

```
sudo apt install default-mysql-server
```

If you would like to install real mySQL database by apt, follow these steps.

Firstly, we need to remove all preceding mysql installed on the host.

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove "^mysql.*"
```

Dowload the stable package mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb from

```
sudo wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb
```

Install the downloaded release package:

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb
```

Refresh your apt package cache to make the new software packages available

```
sudo apt update
```

Install MySQL by executing:

```
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

```
libmysqlclient-dev
```

Check mysql status:

```
sudo service mysql status
```

Comment: worked for me, you can change `sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb` for last version from `https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/` and just edit version number

Answer (score 4):

Yes, should try reinstall mysql, but use the `--reinstall` flag to force a package reconfiguration. So the operating system service configuration is not skipped:

```
sudo apt --reinstall install mysql-server
```

Comment: I guess is just `sudo apt reinstall mysql-server`

Comment: this solution does not work. initial error is there.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed by "purging" every file related to mysql and reinstalling mysql-server:

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to `/etc/systemd/system/`
and do the following

1. `sudo rm -rf mysql.service`
2. `sudo rm -rf mysqld.service`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this command

`sudo systemctl start mysql.service`

Answer (score 1):

Try running

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

if not installed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this also and more (re-installation etc.)

The answer was :
I found `query_cache_limit` and removed it from the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file.

As soon as I removed it, the error log changed to a query_cache_size one
so I removed that one too from `my.cnf` file.
Within seconds, MySQL restarted successfully and I was back in business.

```
* Query Cache Configuration
query_cache_limit = 1M   
query_cache_size  = 16M 
* Logging and Replication
#
```