# cant start mysql server

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, server, ubuntu-20.04

I cannot start Mysql-server on ubuntu 20.04 when I try `systemctl status mysql.service` i got this message:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-08-24 11:27:20 UTC; 12s ago
Process: 46074 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, 
status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 24 11:27:20 virtualmin systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, 
code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 24 11:27:20 virtualmin systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 24 11:27:20 virtualmin systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Aug 24 11:27:20 virtualmin systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart 
counter is at 5.
Aug 24 11:27:20 virtualmin systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Aug 24 11:27:20 virtualmin systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too 
quickly.
Aug 24 11:27:20 virtualmin systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 24 11:27:20 virtualmin systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to start the mysql server in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41147609/unable-to-start-the-mysql-server-in-ubuntu)

Comment: 1) there is no way anyone can tell you what caused your mysql not to start, just based on the fact that it did not start. You need to check mysql error logs. 2) This question has nothing to do with programming, the DBA site offers help in such questions - after you check the error log.

Comment: journalctl -ex

-- The job identifier is 6579 and the job result is done.
Aug 24 12:32:16 virtualmin systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 24 12:32:16 virtualmin systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support

Comment: and this is my log file 

`2021-08-24 9:26:02 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2021-08-24  9:26:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2021-08-24  9:26:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2021-08-24  9:26:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 210824  9:26:02
2021-08-24  9:26:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2021-08-24  9:26:04 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1625479; transaction id 21
2021-08-24  9:26:04 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete`

Answer (score 0):

mostly other service is running on the same port (3306) ,
try

```
netstat -pnltu | grep -i "3306"
```

it will show all services running on that port , if there are any , just end it and restart your Mysql server

Comment: after I check that I have no one service running on the port 3306

Comment: when I type Mysql I got error respond: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'`